# Query an Oracale database and display the results on Splunk

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, splunk, splunk-dashboard, splunk-dbconnect

Does anyone knows if it is possible to query a database using an application like Splunk and representing the data in a Dashboard ? 
I am looking to query an Oracle database as I see Splunk have some plugins for MySQL etc.

Steven

Answer (score 1):

There is a [SQL agnostic App](http://splunk-base.splunk.com/apps/50803/dbx-sql-database-extension) about to be Released in Splunk Base.

In the meanwhile you can use [this example](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0/AdvancedDev/ScriptExample#Script_example.2C_poll_a_database_.28Python.29) to get things going.

I came up with a variation of it which reads any .yaml files (with all the necessary DB and query data) from all subdirs of a a given directory and dumps the results into .csv files which are continually monitored by Splunk.